# Yii2 GridView column data as link to related table attribute

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I am trying to have `GridView` with one column in url link type. This one column is from relation in model `Region` (as `region_type` - FK), specifically name attribute of this related table. In this `GridView` I got no problem to get value of name of these related table, but problem is to provide them as link format instead of plain name. I set `parentRegion.name` as relation attribute in RegionSearch model.

**View**:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            [
                'label' => 'View parent',
                'format' => 'raw',
                // here comes the problem - instead of parent_region I need to have parent
                'value' => function ($dataProvider) {
                     return Html::a('view', '/admin/region/view?id=' . $dataProvider->parent_region);
                 },
            ],

            'parentRegion.name',  // this is what I want to display in link value - name of this related data


            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

**RegionSearch**:

```
public function attributes()
{
            // add related fields to searchable attributes
            return array_merge(parent::attributes(), ['parentRegion', 'regionType']);
}

public function search($params)
{
    $query = Region::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $query->joinWith(['parentRegion' => function($query) { $query->from(['parentRegion' => 'region']); }]);
    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['parentRegion'] = [
        'asc' => ['parentRegion' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['parentRegion' => SORT_DESC],
    ];

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parentRegion', $this->getAttribute('parentRegion')])

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Could you please help me how to get this property name (attribute of related table) to this `GridView` as link?

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
  [
           'label' => 'Name',
           'format' => 'raw',
           'value' => function ($data) {
                         return Html::a($data->parentRegion->name, ['/admin/region/view', 'id' => $data->parent_id]);
                     },
    ],
```

Comment: Not working, I get this exception: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: link appear in gridview ?

Comment: No, I guess this is because $dataProvider has no property parentRegion. This property I can get from model class, but not from $dataProvider. Problem is to have this property in $dataProvider.

Comment: do you have `parentRegion` relation in `Region` model ?

Comment: In my model Region I have  public function getParentRegion() as I know this is I can acces by $model-> parentRegion as classic property

Comment: `ParentRegion` model have name property?

Comment: In this function `$data` refers to the model, not to the provider. Most likely only _one_ of your models is missing it parentRegion. In other words, do something like `if (isset($data->parentRegion)) { return ...; } else { return null; }`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
'format' => 'raw',
'value' => function($data){return Html::a(Html::encode($data->country->name), ['country/view','id' => $data->countryid], ['data-pjax' => 0]);}
```